# How to take the checkbox value as array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three checkbox. I want to get the checked values. I'm using jQuery but I don't get it properly.

**html**

```
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='' class='group1' value=""/>Period 1</label>
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='' class='group1' value="" class='termcls' />period 2</label>
<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='' class='group1' value=""/>All</label>
```

**jQuery**

```
var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.group1').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

alert(values[0]);
```

Comment: how can i gel all checked values like [0],[1]

Comment: Use `return  [this.value];`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ntge1vxu/1/ ?

Answer (score 3):

simply try

```
var values =[];
$('input.group1:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    value.push( this.value );
});

console.log( values );
```

Since Arun hasn't posted an answer, so shameless copying it from his [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ntge1vxu/1/) here :)

```
$('input:checkbox.group1').change(function() {
  var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.group1').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  alert(values);
})
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny why not answer :) your code is totally working

Comment: @Rose, refer to the fiddle given by Arun above.

Answer (score 2):

Put values for each checkbox and use like this

```js
function getoutput() {
  var values = [];
  $('.group1:checked').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='' class='group1' value="1" />Period 1</label>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='' class='group1' value="2" class='termcls' />period 2</label>
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='' class='group1' value="3" />All</label>

<input type="button" value="Get Selected" onclick="getoutput()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for each to look over the values then use ".is(':checked')" to check which ones are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  this

*note:* `value` is blank in your html right now, there must be a value to get it into the `.map()` function

```
var values = $('input.group1:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
   return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

---

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/11cqkawL/)